# Javascript to return last 6 months and then use each month as a variable

Tags: javascript

Hopefully someone can help.

I have the following function to return the last 6 monthly names (I.E June, July, August etc), however, I cannot work out how I would then use each returned month name as separate variables.

I need this so I can feed each month name in to an sql query that populates a table for the last 6 months.

Any help much appreciated.

```
function getMonths()
    {
        var today = new Date();             
        var month = 1;
        var currMonth = month-3;

        var monthArray = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June",
                "July","August","September","October","November","December");

        var menuMonths = new Array();
        var count = 6;
        var buffer = 10;

        while(count >0)
        {           
            if (currMonth < 0)
                currMonth += 12;
            if (currMonth >=12 )
                currMonth -= 12;

            var month = monthArray[currMonth];
            menuMonths.push(month);

            currMonth = currMonth -1;
            count = count -1;
        }       
        return (menuMonths.reverse());
    } 


console.log (getMonths());
```

Comment: `use each returned month name as separate variables` is easy but very probably not what you need. Don't do that.

Comment: If you're running a sql query, you're using Server code. You should do this either server side or database side...

Comment: @Bartdude He could use it client side, on a SQLite DB

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

**FIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/BeNdErR/NF5Qm/1/

**CODE**

```
var monthArray = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June",
            "July","August","September","October","November","December");

var currMonth = 3; // the current month index, from 1 to 12
var firstMonth = currMonth - 6;

if(firstMonth < 0){ //for example if currMonth is January - 0
    var months = [];
    months.push(monthArray.slice(12 - Math.abs(firstMonth), 12));
    months.push(monthArray.slice(0, currMonth));
    alert(months);
}else{
    alert(monthArray.slice(firstMonth, currMonth))
}
```

As output, you still have an array, so you can pass it to the SQL Query as it is, for example (SQLite):

```
tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE month = ? OR month = ? month = ? OR month = ? month = ? OR month = ?;", [slicedMonthArray], successCB, errorCB);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
var months = getMonths();

for(var i=0, len=months.length; i<len; i++){
   var currentMonth =  months[i];
   alert(currentMonth);
   //do whatever you want here;

}
```